# Debugging Python in Visual Studio Code from a WSL2 instance produces no output

Tags: python, vscode-debugger, wsl-2

I'm on a Windows 10 (Build 19044) host machine and running an Ubuntu 18.04 instance in a WSL2 container. Using VS Code with the Microsoft Python extension installed.

When I try to run or debug a python file in VS Code (pressing F5 while window with file is active) the "RUN AND DEBUG" view opens and nothing else happens - no output is produced and the code doesn't run.

I've tried:

- adding `"python.defaultInterpreterPath" :"/usr/bin/python3` to my settings.json file
- adding `"linux": {"name": "Launch[linux]", "type": "python", "request": "launch", "program": "${file}"}` to my launch.json file

I can run the python scripts in the integrated terminal just fine.
Currently out of ideas to try next. All guides online say it should just work.